# Python json.loads() failing for json with escape characters

Tags: python, json

I have some JSON that's formatted incorrectly, and I'm not able to change the way the data comes in, so it's failing within json.loads(str)

The input string comes in the following format:
`str = "{\"targetfid\":33,\"targetval\":\"~!@#$%^&*,,,,()_+:\"?<,,./';[]\\\",\"models_dbid\":\"dbidvalue\"}"`

I've tried doing `json.loads(json.dumps(str))` but this converts it to a string instead of a dictionary, and wrapping it in another json.loads fails. Are there any suggestions for dealing with the escape characters within the string?

Comment: If you have text that is not `json`, then you can't use the `json` module. You either have to make your own parser, or somehow convert it back to real `json` first.

Comment: "I have some JSON that's formatted incorrectly" *then you don't have JSON*

Comment: Try to replace the \ Like myjson.replace("\","") and the try to prase

Comment: I'm asking how to convert an invalid JSON string to JSON, how to deal with escape characters within. I understand it's not formatted as JSON now.

Comment: You need to know exactly what about it is invalid. We can't possibly tell what all the possible invalid strings you may come across.

Comment: Is it this exact string every time? Is not how about `print(json.loads(str1.replace("\\\"", "\\\\\"").replace("\"?", "\\\"?")))`

Comment: The sample string shown can be fixed but surely what you really want is a generic solution - and that's going to be [virtually] impossible. The problem is, unless you know what's broken, you don't know what to fix

Comment: No, it can be any string, but it already comes formatted with \", or \\ for any esc characters. So I am looking for a generic solution ideally

Comment: If its the case that you've been *told* that `"I'm not able to change the way the data comes"`, then you are being played. If its the case that a mistake has been made that produces the data you find yourself with, then that mistake *has* to be fixed. You must never be in the position to 'fix' `json` after the fact.

Comment: along with escape characters, also need to consider that you discard invalid chars too. So @quamrana recommended, you need to write a parser function/module, and as you learn more about it keep on improving it.